# Prove that $P(x)=(1- x+ x^2 -x^3... - x^{99} +x^{100})$ $\times$ $(1 + x +x^2 + x^3... + x^{99} + x^{100})$ doesn't have any odd degree of x member

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, polynomials

You can't use the fact that $P(x)=P(-x)$.

I have noticed two geometric series.
When I multiply each bracket I get $ P(x)=((x^{101}+1)/(x+1))*((x^{101}+1)/(x-1)) $
or $(x^{101}+1)^2/[(x+1)(x-1)]$
I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: Please dont downvote the question because of my bad editing skills.I dont know how to format degree of a number that has more than one digits.

Comment: I did and I got $(x^101 +1)/(x+1)(x-1)$

Comment: To avoid getting downvoted, you should add additional context: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960 For example, show the work that you've already done and where you got stuck in your question.

Comment: ok I will try to explain

Answer (score 1):

You made a typo when converting the geometric series using the sums formula.

You converted the first series correctly:
$$1-x+x^2-x^3...-x^{99}+x^{100}=\frac{x^{101}+1}{x+1}$$

However, the second series is not right, it should be:
$$1+x+x^2+x^3...+x^{99}+x^{100}=\frac{x^{101}-1}{x-1}$$
Notice how there is $-1$ in the numerator, not $+1$. This is where your typo was.

Then, when we multiply them, we get:
$$\frac{x^{101}+1}{x+1}\cdot \frac{x^{101}-1}{x-1}=\frac{x^{202}-1}{x^2-1}$$

Finally, notice that the right-hand side is also in the form of a geometric series sum formula:
$$\frac{x^{202}-1}{x^2-1}=\frac{(x^2)^{101}-1}{x^2-1}=1+x^2+(x^2)^2+...+(x^2)^{100}=1+x^2+x^4+...+x^{200}$$
and there are no odd-degree terms in this polynomials.